# Power system of the 10,000 year clock

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I've heard that the [10,000 year clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_of_the_Long_Now) will use multiple power sources (heat differential, mechanical weight, etc.), but how are they all integrated?

Comment: On a related note.  The design of the prototype clock have been published in great detail ([PDF 17MB](http://static.longnow.org/media/ClockPlans01.pdf), CAD files can be found [here](http://longnow.org/clock/prototype1/) ).  On the other hand, the prototype is powered only by weights, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @NickAlexeev In his reference they say " ... If there is no attention for long periods of time the Clock uses the energy captured by changes in the temperature between day and night on the mountain top above to power its time-keeping apparatus....". Also [**here**](http://longnow.org/clock/) some reference to the use of a "differential mechanism" and "long rods" to transfer thermal power. Whether implemented I know not.

Comment: Mechanically combining energy input from various low speed sources could be done by a range of means. An "escapement" with different pawls, pressurisation of a vessel driving a piston,  differential or stacked differentials eg jack up rwd car with two wheels off ground - lock one rear wheel and drive other to rotate drive shaft. Works for other wheel an this could drive additional versions in series with N+1 inputs for N differentials. Efficiency may be problematic.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - FYI, I added in the Wikipedia source; I don't know if s/he had others.